# Typesense: Firebase Function timeout using Typesense client

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, timeout, typesense

I have a Firebase function trigger for when an item is updated. In most instances this function completes and updates the item in the Typesense database however, occasionaly this function fails with a timeout.

This happens seemingly randomly for this and other **onCreate** and **onUpdate** Firebase Functions using the Typesense client.

**Failed Function Screenshot Example** (output from https://console.cloud.google.com/logs)
[Logs when function times out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5hra.png)

**Succesful Function Screenshot Example**
[Logs when function behaves as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlZVn.png)

**Firebase Function:**

```
// Firebase function triggered when a program is updated
export const onUpdate = functions
  // 256MB memory and timeout of 2 minutes
  .runWith({ memory: '256MB', timeoutSeconds: 120 })
  .firestore.document('programs/{docId}')
  .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
    const id = context.params.docId;
    const data = snap.data();

    const client = useTypesense();

    const item = { ...data, id };

    console.log('Typesense: Updating Program');
    await client
      .collections('programs')
      .documents()
      .upsert(item)
      .then(() => {
        console.log(`Typesense: Program ${item.id} successfully updated!`);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Typesense: Error creating Program: ' + item.id, error);
      });

    return null;
  });
```

**useTypesense() function** (Initializing the client)

```
import Typesense from 'typesense';

const useTypesense = () => {
  const host = 'api.oniworkout.app'
  const port = '443'
  const protocol = 'https'
  const apiKey = 'b3fxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx';

  console.log(
    `Typesense: Initializing client with host: ${host}, port: ${port}, protocol: ${protocol}, apiKey: ${apiKey.substring(
      0,
      3
    )}`
  );

  const client = new Typesense.Client({
    nodes: [
      {
        host,
        port,
        protocol,
      },
    ],
    apiKey,
    connectionTimeoutSeconds: 120,
    retryIntervalSeconds: 120,
  });

  return client;
};
```

- I have tried extending the duration of timeout on the Firebase Function from 60 seconds to 120 seconds. The issue persists.
- I haved checked https://api.oniworkout.app/health which returns {"ok":true}

Comment: Sporadic timeouts usually happen when the server running Typesense is either out of RAM or CPU. Could you make sure that you have [sufficient RAM / CPU capacity](https://typesense.org/docs/guide/system-requirements.html)?

Comment: I believe the RAM and CPU are sufficient. My VPS hosting has 2GB RAM and 2 Cores CPU. Over the last month CPU usage has reached 5% twice otherwise it is barely active. RAM went to 1.4GB used once, otherwise, it consistently sits between 0.6GB and 1GB usage.

Comment: Is there some way to view Typesense logs so I can check for anything happening on the Typesense server when these issues occur?